# How to add dropdown list which contains all element in my product list

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I can iterate over different products using

```
<li
{ % if not category % }class = "selected" {% endif % }>

<a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}">All</a>

</li>

{% for c in categories %}

    <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

this is my code for a dropdown list, but it is not showing anything after books.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown ">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Categories
    </a>
    <p class=" dropdown-menu ">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}">All</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Electronics</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Books</a>

    <ul>
        <li {% if not category %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}">All</a>
        </li>
        {% for c in categories %}
            <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    </p>
</li>
```

---

I want to add this code to my dropdown list

```
        <li {% if not category %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}">All</a>
        </li>
        {% for c in categories %}
            <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

but this code is showing nothing in the drop down list

my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Category, Product


def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    return render(request, 'shop/products/list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    })
```

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: where is `categories` defined? show us your view.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is because you are nesting a `ul` inside a `p` and it is invalid HTML.